# regular expression to work on html

Tags: javascript, regex, html

I want my page to splurt a message if my pattern matches my regex and I don't know why this is not doing anything.

html:

```
<div class="third">
        <label> Enter Password: </label>
        <input type="text" name="pword1" class="iBox" id="pword1" onmouseout="HideToolTip()" onmouseover="ShowToolTip()" onkeyup="allFunctions()" placeholder="choose a password" autocomplete="off">
        <p id="tooltipbox">Password must be between 8-16 characters, contain an uppercase, lowercase, number and special character</p>
</div>
```

js:

```
function reqMetVal(){
    var pwfs = document.getElementById("pword1").value;
    var re = "^(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[\\\+\=\.,\[\]_£|\`¬':\;\~{}<>()#?!\@$\%^&*-]).{8,20}$";

    if(pwfs.match(re)){
        DIMR = "Requirements MET";

    }else if (pwfs.length < 1){
        DIMR = "";
    }
    else{
        DIMR = "Requirements NOT MET";
    }
    document.getElementById("reqMeeting").innerHTML = DIMR;
}
```

Comment: You are not calling your function anywhere...

Comment: Use forward slash as a regex delimiter.

Comment: Would strongly recommend writing multiple separate validation checks instead of the massive regex, i.e. check string length, check existence of capitals, check special characters etc. Will be a thousand times clearer for you to maintain and likely even quicker due to the complexity of a lookahead regex.

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh i have a function called allFunctions() which i am calling and inside that it looks like this. `function allFunctions(){
 passwordValidation();
 reqMetVal();
}`

Comment: @AvinashRaj what do you mean by that?

Comment: @Martin i understand what you are saying in terms of for maintability etc. but i want to at least get this working first before i adapt. can you see why it is not working?

Comment: Are there any errors in console ? Also, add `console.log("reqMetVal called")` in your `reqMetVal` function.

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh okay so done that. and i get this in the console: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null exampleJS2.html:129 reqMetVal exampleJS2.html:61 allFunctionsexampleJS2.html:36 onkeyup`

Comment: So `document.getElementById("reqMeeting")` is null. That means there is no element with which has id `reqMeeting`.

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh ah yes. right i have now set getElementById to "pword1" and im still not getting the required results. console throwing no errors

Comment: Add a new element... some `<div id="reqMeeting"></div>` .

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh cheers man. almost there. that is now bringing up the text but what it is doing is replacing the text box with the text if you get me. here is an image of before and after. second image is after i type just one character. `http://www.tiikoni.com/tis/view/?id=025ef7f`, second image `http://www.tiikoni.com/tis/view/?id=d28c06c`

Comment: That's why add a new element with some id, and use that element to display the message text instead of your password text box.